# MYSQL SELECT where all results in sub query are NULL

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

`Accounts` table:

```
account_id        | account_name 
--------------------------------
12345             | Demo Account
678910            | Acme Inc.
```

And `Users` table:

```
user_id           | account_id          | user_name           | last_login
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
66666             | 12345               | john.doe            | 2021-08-23
77777             | 12345               | jane.doe            | NULL
88888             | 678910              | user_one            | NULL
99999             | 678910              | user_two            | NULL
```

Is it possible to create a single query that returns only the account IDs where **none** of the users have ever logged in (Meaning `last_login` is NULL)?

With such a query, the only result should be `678910`.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM Account a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users u
                  WHERE u.account_id = a.account_id AND u.last_login IS NOT NULL);
```

Read in plain English, the above query says to return any account for which we *cannot* find a record in the `Users` table having a non null `last_login` value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
 Try the following query:

 Select account_id from accounts where account_id IN (Select account_id from users where last_login is not null;
```